# How can I count how many items appear once, twice, thrice, ...?

Tags: python, pandas, count

I have a dataframe df:

```
number 
123
123
123
456
456
789
111
111
111
...
```

I would like to know how many items appear X times.

Output should be something like this:

```
X times | count
3       | 2    (123 + 111 appear 3 times and are 2 numbers)
2       | 1    (456 appears 2 times but only 1 number)
1       | 1    (111 appear 1 time but only 1 number)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use double [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df1 = (df['number'].value_counts()
                   .value_counts()
                   .rename_axis('X times')
                   .reset_index(name='count'))
print (df1)
   X times  count
0        3      2
1        2      1
2        1      1
```

Alternative with double [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
s = df.groupby('number').size()
df1 = (s.groupby(s).size()
        .rename_axis('X times')
        .reset_index(name='count'))
print (df1)
   X times  count
0        1      1
1        2      1
2        3      2
```

Or combination, thank you @Ch3steR:

```
df1 = (df.groupby('number')
         .size()
         .value_counts()
         .rename_axis('X times')
         .reset_index(name='count'))
```

Comment: double groupby is redundant `s = df.groupby('number').size().value_counts()`?

Comment: @Ch3steR - Yop, agree ;)

Comment: Found a third solution: `from collections import Counter`

`Counter(df["number"].value_counts().tolist())`